# KNow nothing about ssl , how to setup apache to run with ssl?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

I have an ubuntu server with apache installed 
i run a game on the server and want to integrate it to facebook
but it is required to be through HTTPS :s
how can i move the game to run on https ?

i will be grateful for any links/hints .

Thank you .

Comment: You can find many tutorials on how to do it.

Comment: Ok , where , google is sick of me already !

Comment: @RonanDejhero From the FAQ "Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support **professionals**", please make an effort before posting here.

Comment: @sam Thanks for your info ! i came here after trying couple of tutorials which broke my server , and i wrote this question after managing to fix it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are required to buy a SSL certificate.
2. Follow the instructions as given in: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/forum/server/apache2/SSL