# Configuring SSL in apache web server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KNow nothing about ssl , how to setup apache to run with ssl?](https://serverfault.com/questions/337730/know-nothing-about-ssl-how-to-setup-apache-to-run-with-ssl)

I am trying to find out the configuration steps for configuring my apache with SSL (https). The server in use is an Red hat linux machine, and apache is already installed in it (comes by default with linux).

How can I configure this apache (or install apache with ssl) on linux machine? I have already done it on my windows machine, but do not have any idea of configurations on linux machine.

Comment: Why would Apache under Linux be much different than Apache under Windows? See [`mod_ssl`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) for full details of configuring Apache's TLS support.

Comment: IMHO this question does not belong to stackoverflow: should be moved to superuser.com

Comment: Have you read the manual (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/) yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `yum install mod_ssl` on your rig to get SSL up and running. After that you should give some more information what you want to configure. Study the `ssl.conf` (or similar named file) which gets installed on your system. It is very well documented.

Additionally I'd suggest reading the Apache SSL documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Configuring apache is identical regardless of the OS used.

The only difference is in the actual filesystem locations used (not even in the format of these paths): Windows uses C:/httpd/etc and Unix uses /etc/httpd (for example).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a RHEL box, the steps are well covered in the deployment guide:

- RHEL 6: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Deployment_Guide/index.html -> 14.1.8
- RHEL 5: http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/Deployment_Guide/index.html -> 23.8